# How to handle connection pooling in Oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, connection-pooling

We have lots of micro services which need connection to DB. Oracle and PostgreSQL can handle just limited amount of connections. PostgreSQL solve this situation with PgBouncer so application connect to this URL which handle connection pooling. Is there something similar in Oracle ? What I found is oracle [UCP](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/configuring-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-in-a-springboot-project-take-2) but I think this is still pooling in application not in DB.

Comment: A true connection pool *must* be managed by the client, as it needs module-level integration with the application to work. Oracle Shared Server architecture would be the closest server-side equivalent. It is ideal for situations where you need to conserve resources and support lots of short, simultaneous connections. If you have the Enterprise Edition, Oracle Connection Manager can also provide some connection consolidation.

Comment: Check [DRCP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/drcp.htm#JJDBC29023)

Comment: I agree DRCP is the first thing to look at.  You would probably want to use a UCP pool in the app as well, so connections from the app don't need recreating.  If you want a true mid-tier pool solution in Oracle, use [CMAN-TDM](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1553699580893001bF1R/PF/PDF-OOW19-DEV4692-CMAN-TDM_1569295711808001cYvb.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If your clients drivers are not too old (pre oracle-12) you can use Oracles Database Resident Connection Pooling.
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/database-resident-connection-pooling.html#GUID-D4F9DBD7-7DC6-4233-B831-933809173E39

Database Resident Connection Pooling
Database Resident Connection Pool (DRCP) is a connection pool in the server that is shared across many clients. You should use DRCP in connection pools where the number of active connections is fairly less than the number of open connections.

Especially database administrators will love this because they can have a good control on the hits on the database.

Comment: thx a lot, and it is safe to use this when we have 2PC transaction in our application ?

Comment: I did not test that but if all tx behave correctly I expect it would. Otherwise you hit a bug. Test it.